# Infinite product of $(1-1/2n)$ terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, infinite-product

What is the value of the infinite product
$$ \frac{1}{2} \frac{3}{4} \frac{5}{6}\cdots = 
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n-1}{2n} =
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{2n}\right) =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2 n)!!}$$

What is the asymptotic of the product as a function of $n$ for large $n$?

Comment: @Ross Millikan You are right, corrected the formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply Stirling's Formula to $$\frac{(2n)!}{(2^nn!)^2}$$

Comment: Very good answer, sterling formula $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \log(N!)=N\log{N}-N$,

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar: there is an additional $\frac 12 \log (2 \pi N)$.  It doesn't look like it matters here.

Answer (score 5):

*Without Stirling, but only comparison theorems for series with non-negative terms:*

Letting $a_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} 1-\frac{1}{2n}$,
$$\begin{align*}
 \ln \prod_{n=1}^N a_n &= \sum_{n=1}^N \ln a_n = \sum_{n=1}^N \ln \left(1-\frac{1}{2n}\right) \operatorname*{=}_{N\to\infty} - \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2n}- \sum_{n=1}^N \underbrace{\left( \frac{1}{4n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)}_{\stackrel{\rm def}{=} b_n}
\\&= -\frac{1}{2}H_N - \sum_{n=1}^N b_n \tag{1}
\end{align*}$$
using the fact that $\ln (1+x) \operatorname*{=}_{x\to0} x - \frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$. Now, recall that $H_N \operatorname*{=}_{N\to\infty} \ln N + \gamma + o(1)$ to get
$$\begin{align*}
 \ln \prod_{n=1}^N a_n &= -\frac{1}{2}\ln N - \frac{1}{2}\gamma +o(1) - \sum_{n=1}^N b_n\tag{2}
\end{align*}$$
and, since $\sum_{n=1}^N b_n$ converges (by comparison with $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}$) to *some* real value (call it $c$), 
$$\begin{align*}
 \ln \prod_{n=1}^N a_n &= -\frac{1}{2}\ln N - \frac{1}{2}\gamma - c + o(1)\,.\tag{3}
\end{align*}$$
By continuity of exponential, this gives"
$$\begin{align*}
 \prod_{n=1}^N a_n &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}\gamma - c}\cdot e^{o(1)}\,.\tag{4}
\end{align*}$$
and, since $\lim_{N\to\infty}e^o(1) = 1$, we get
$$\begin{align*}
 \boxed{ \prod_{n=1}^N a_n \operatorname*{\sim}_{N\to\infty} \frac{C}{\sqrt{N}} }
\end{align*}$$
for some positive constant $C\stackrel{\rm def}{=} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\gamma - c}$.

Comment: Note: that constant $C$ is actually (as found using other methods) equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$.